# OpenGL ES 2.0 getAttributeLocation returning -1

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm attempting to color an object in openGL ES 2.0 for android but when I call the following it returns -1.

```
int mColorHandle = GLES20.getAttributeLocation(mProgram,"iColor");
```

Shader:

```
private static final String sFragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;"
        + "uniform vec4 iColor;"
        + "void main() {"
        + " gl_FragColor = iColor;" + "}";
```

Method call in context:

```
mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragShader);
GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

int mColorHandle = GLES20.getAttributeLocation(mProgram,"iColor");
Log.i(TAG,"mColorHandle: "+Integer.toString(mColorHandle));
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Attributes and uniforms are different things. You're calling `glGetAttributeLocation()` for a uniform variable in the shader code.

Comment: Calling `glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"iColor")` solves it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared iColor as a uniform, so you'll need to call GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"iColor") if you're actually using it as a uniform variable (which is to say, one iColor value for many different primitives).

if you have a buffer of iColor values, one for each vertex, then you'll need to declare iColor as "attrib vec4 iColor;" in your shader. After you do that, your call to GLES20.glGetAttributeLocation(mProgram,"iColor") should return a valid location.